# Can you use Reactjs with ee?

Tags: add-on, ee, api

I am new to EE (also coding so might seem naive) and was wondering if there is any way to connect my ReactJS project, that i created with create-react-app, with EE. 
create-react-app docs here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

I have been looking around but not too many examples with React.

Would it be possible by using CMS as an API (with an add-on?) where I would fetch the data in the React app and if this is a viable way to go about it, how would I go about doing it?

My version of EE is v4.3.6
React version is v16.6.1

Thanks

Comment: Just for the sake of Google Search and this popping up... You can with:
reinos.nl - webservice - addon
But how it suits your needs varies.

Answer (score 0):

Using EE as a content API is not possible as far as I know. The only API EE provides is an interface to add, update, delete entries.

A workaround could be found here by just outputting JSON: [How to make templates output JSON?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/695/how-to-make-templates-output-json) but this is still not that flexible and dynamic and gets complicated when working with 3rd party and custom add-ons.

We thought about to implement the content API ourself and just use EE as content creation. But actually, we stick to the approach to use a real headless CMS.